# JModel error when getting article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I'm writing a Joomla 2.5.3 module. I'm trying to get an article from a JModel.

```
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model =& JModel::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$item =& $model->getItem((int) $id);
```

The result is:

```
Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /var/www/site/joomla/components/com_content/models/article.php on line 170
```

Does anyone know why?

---

*EDIT*:

Line 170 of `/var/www/site/joomla/component/com_content/models/article.php` is

```
$data->params = clone $this->getState('params');
```

If I do `var_dump($tihs->getState('params'))` I get `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error myself. The code is this:

```
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model =& JModel::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));

$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);

$item =& $model->getItem($id);
```

The error was:

```
Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /var/www/site/joomla/components/com_content/models/article.php on line 170
```

Looking at the source code of class `ContentModelArticle` (in `components/com_content/models/application.php`) I noticed that the function `getItem()` try to access the variable `$params` of the state object. That variable is not previously initialized.

```
$registry = new JRegistry;
$registry->loadString($data->attribs);
$data->params = clone $this->getState('params'); // 'params' was not previously initialized! The call to clone will fail if you don't provide your own initialization.
$data->params->merge($registry);
```

The code above gets the article’s private attributes and then tries to override the global attributes.

Before the call to `$model->getItem($id)` I supplied the global article attributes to the state object with the lines:

```
$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
```

Now it works.